# How to wait for the user input without using slots (Synchronous and Asynchronous actions)

Tags: python, telegram, chatbot, rasa, rasa-nlu

Hi i am building a bot in rasa and my issue is that :

I have an intent location and an action behind this intent the action is to build a button and send it via the dispatcher the story goes as follows:

```
- story: localisation
  steps:
  - intent: localisation
  - action: action_loc_searching
```

in the actions file i have the following instructions :

```
   #build the button paload in jsonaa andsend it via the dispatcher to the channel
    dispatcher.utter_message(json_message=jsonaa)
    # await asyncio.sleep(5) 
    message = tracker.latest_message['text']
    print(message)
```

the button is used to retrieve the user’s location. Once he clicks on it, the location is sent to the bot. Now the problem is that I can retrieve the location sent to the bot beacause the bot continues on the other instructions before the user has pressed the button. So when i print the message i have the last text entered by the user (the on that triggered the action). The actions after the uter_message are executed before the bot receives the location.

It would be great if someone can help !